# Tombstoning selected items of Multiselect List( wp7 mango tool kit control)

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How i can Tombstone the selected values of a multiselect list control. I retrieve the values of selected items by iterating through the statement [((System.Collections.Generic.List)(items))] , but i am flailed   to reassign this values, any one please help me to solve this issue. It seems this is a blocking issue form me, only countable days left for my marketplace submission. So any one please help  me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (selectedItems != null && selectedItems.Count > 0) { 
    wordlist.IsSelectionEnabled = true; 
    ObservableCollection<Word> wrdlst = new ObservableCollection<Word>(); 
    var vm = this.DataContext as wordsListVM; 
    wrdlst = vm.WordsList; 
    ItemContainerGenerator itemContainerGenerator = this.wordlist.ItemContainerGenerator; 
    foreach (Word word in wrdlst) {
        if (word != null) { 
            foreach (string wordId in selectedItems) { 
                if (wordId == word.Id) { 
                   DependencyObject visualItem = itemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(word); 
                   MultiselectItem multiselectItem = visualItem as MultiselectItem; 
                   if (multiselectItem != null) { 
                       multiselectItem.IsSelected = true; 
                   } 
                } 
             } 
         } 
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try listBox.SelectedItems.Add(item1);

Comment: i am talking about tombstoning selected items in "multiselect list" in this context where the selected item will come

Comment: Then you would need to do something like foreach(var item in tombstonedSelection) listBox.SelectedItems.Add(item);

You'd first have to store the selection somewhere - e.g. in the page.State dictionary - this.State["ListBoxSelection"] = selection; and later var tombstonedSelection = (List<ItemType>)this.State["ListBoxSelection"];